# Trouble installing rpm package

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, installation, package-management

This is probably a dumb question. I need to install the rpm package as listed here: http://www.securityspace.com/smysecure/catid.html?in=CESA-2012:0467 but I simply don't know where it is hosted. I run `rpm -Uvh freetype-2.2.1-31.el5_8.1.x86_64.rpm` but I get `error: open of freetype-2.2.1-31.el5_8.1.x86_64.rpm failed: No such file or directory`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you download it to? And why don't you just install the updated package provided by your distribution?

Comment: I didn't download it to anywhere. Maybe I need to `wget` it first?

Comment: and how do I find the updated package provided by my distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just update your system normally, and you should receive the updated package, or an even later version which fixes even more bugs and security problems.

```
# yum update freetype
```

Or update the whole system, since it's quite possible you haven't done that in much longer than you should:

```
# yum update
```